# Cant store double in NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, xcode6

When trying to store a double in an Object I get an error

```
 error Sending 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'
```

My code is:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts"     inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newDevice setValue:longitudes forKey:@"longitude"];
    [newDevice setValue:latitudes  forKey:@"latitude"];


setValue:longitudes
```

longitudes is of type double.

Comment: What is the type of `longitudes` and `latitudes`?

Comment: `[newDevice setValue:@(longitudes) forKey:@"longitude"];` and `[newDevice setValue:@(latitudes) forKey:@"latitude"];`, perhaps?

Comment: Ok, you can't pass a value of primitive type to `-setValue:forKey:` method. Value should be of type _id_ (any Objective-c class). Ho to cast double to NSNumber is allready shown in the other answers.

Comment: As a side note: you can subclass NSManagedObject (using XCode's generator). Then you will have explicitly typed properties, which make development easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use NSNumber to store double value.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts"     inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newDevice setValue:@(longitudes) forKey:@"longitude"];
[newDevice setValue:@(latitudes)  forKey:@"latitude"];
```

So it should work.

You can also write:

```
NSNumber *longitudesNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitudes];
NSNumber *latitudesNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitudes];
[newDevice setValue: longitudesNumber forKey:@"longitude"];
[newDevice setValue: latitudesNumber   forKey:@"latitude"];
```

Better to understand :)

To show, u can use:

```
NSNumber *number = ...(your object);

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", number];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [number doubleValue]];
```

Comment: @Matz one more question please if i want to convert label.text to double is it possible ??

Comment: @Matz [newDevice setValue:self.longitudelable.text forKey:@"descrip"];

Comment: i want to add this line to the object above i posted it first but the value i need is a label i want to convert it to double in order to save it in the data base

Comment: Okay. Use @([self.longitudelable.text doubleValue]) and put it into your object.

Comment: i want to convert the longitudelabel to double is ther a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this

```
[newDevice setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitudes] forKey:@"longitude"];
[newDevice setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitudes]  forKey:@"latitude"];
```

Comment: one more question please if i want to convert label.text to double is it possible ??

Comment: Yes you can convert it like this double aDval = [label.text doubleValue];

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

`[newDevice setValue:longitudes forKey:@"longitude"];`

...is using a [key-value coding method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:) to set the value, and key-value coding methods require value objects. This is the method signature for `setValue:forKey:`:

`- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key`

The exception is happening because you are passing a double to the value parameter. Your NSManagedObject subclass can - and should - use scalars and not NSNumber to represent doubles, you just can't use `setValue:forKey:` without wrapping the values in an NSValue class first. You can, however, use traditional notation or dot notation to set the value with a double:

`[newDevice setLongitude:longitudes];`

or

`newDevice.longitude = longitudes;`